# Json Mapping using Apache Velocity Template

Tags: java, json, apache, mapping, velocity

I have a json response which I am converting to xml using the Apache Valocity template. My json is in this format :

```
{
    "value": {
        "1234": {
            "7": ["abcde"],
            "2": ["abcde", "lkisy", "skjsk"],
            "1": ["aksdja", "msnd", "knsda"]
        },
        "7654": {
            "8": ["NA"],
            "4": ["NA"],
            "7": ["BA"]
        },
        "0987": {
            "8": ["PO"],
            "3": ["LO"],
            "2": ["KI"]
        }

    }
}
```

My velocity template is in this format :

```
<VelocityResponse xmlns="xsd location namespace">
<HeaderID>${headers.HeaderID}</HeaderID>
<FirstTag>
#foreach($body in ${body.value})
<SecondTag>
#set($keys = $body.keySet())
#foreach($key in $keys)
<ThirdTag>$key</ThirdTag>
#set($someValue = $key.keySet())
#foreach($value in $someValue)
<FourthTag>$value</FourthTag>
<FifthTag>
#foreach($userInfo in $someValue[$value])
<SixthTag>$userInfo</SixthTag>
#end
</FifthTag>
#end
</SecondTag>
#end
</FirstTag>
</VelocityResponse>
```

When I try to map this, I recieve this error :

```
198 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.15.1.redhat-621084 | Error : org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "<EOF>" at org.apache.camel.component.velocity.VelocityEndpoint[line 21, column 27]
n  | Was expecting one of:
n  |     "(" ...
n  |     <RPAREN> ...
n  |     <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ...
n  |     <SET_DIRECTIVE> ...
n  |     "##" ...
n  |     "\\\\" ...
n  |     "\\" ...
n  |     <TEXT> ...
n  |     "*#" ...
n  |     "*#" ...
n  |     "]]#" ...
n  |     <STRING_LITERAL> ...
n  |     <END> ...
n  |     <IF_DIRECTIVE> ...
n  |     <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
n  |     <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
n  |     <WORD> ...
n  |     <BRACKETED_WORD> ...
n  |     <IDENTIFIER> ...
n  |     <DOT> ...
n  |     "{" ...
n  |     "}" ...
n  |     <EMPTY_INDEX> ...
n  |
```

Got any  ideas   ?

Comment: Please check if all variables used in velocity template are also in the velocity model.  Not sure, it is correct in the first foreach,  "${body.value}". If body is in your model, try also to access it in the template with getters, like $body.getValue()

Comment: Hi, actually I am getting the value.

Answer (score 1):

So after head storming for some time. I came up with the proper xml structure :

```
<VelocityResponse xmlns="xsd location namespace">
<HeaderID>${headers.HeaderID}</HeaderID>
<FirstTag>
#foreach($body in ${body.value})
#set($keys = $body.keySet())
#foreach($key in $keys)
<SecondTag>
<ThirdTag>$key</ThirdTag>
<NewTag>
#set($somevalue = $body[$key].keySet())
#foreach($input in $somevalue)
<FourthTag>$input</FourthTag>
<FifthTag>
#foreach($userInfo in $body[$key][$input])
<SixthTag>$userInfo</SixthTag>
#end
</FifthTag>
#end
</NewTag>
</SecondTag>
#end
#end
</FirstTag>
</VelocityResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a typo maybe, but we're missing an #end. (foreach on thirdtag)
Try with this template:

```
<VelocityResponse xmlns="xsd location namespace">
    <HeaderID>${headers.HeaderID}</HeaderID>
    <FirstTag>
        #foreach($body in ${body.value})
        <SecondTag>
            #set($keys = $body.keySet())
            #foreach($key in $keys)
                <ThirdTag>$key</ThirdTag>
            #end
            #set($someValue = $key.keySet())
            #foreach($value in $someValue)
            <FourthTag>$value</FourthTag>
            <FifthTag>
                #foreach($userInfo in $someValue[$value])
                <SixthTag>$userInfo</SixthTag>
                #end
            </FifthTag>
            #end
        </SecondTag>
        #end
    </FirstTag>
</VelocityResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing '#end' tag, it was a typo. Dont you think the second foreach block should not end after mapping the ThirdTag ?

Comment: It depends on your business logic. You decide base on your output you desire. If the answer helped you mark it as useful.